# Mongos bug may due to route cache

Tags: mongodb

Some data lose when i restart mongos process.

It can reoccurrence by such step.

1. Create a collection test without shard on database test.

```
use test
db.test.insert({"k": 1})
```

2. Change config.datebases to another shard.

```
use config

db.databases.find({"_id": "test"})
{ "_id" : "test", "primary" : "rs2_1", "partitioned" : false }

db.databases.update({"_id": "test"}, {"$set": {"primary": "rs1_1"}})

db.databases.find({"_id": "test"})
{ "_id" : "test", "primary" : "rs1_1", "partitioned" : false }
```

3. At this time, i can find data already

```
use test
db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63f74df722fe0bf5b3d2d284"), "k" : 1}
```

4. Restart mongos progress

```
kill 123
mongos -f /home/mongodb/mongo.conf
```

5. I can't found my data!!!!!

```
db.test.find()
```

Here's how I guess it happened.

1. A collection without shard, use config.datebases to route.
2. Mongos cache route in memory.
3. Update config.datebases will not affect memory cache.
4. Restart mongos will use route in config.datebases

How i fix it or avoid recurrence?

Comment: "_How i fix it or avoid recurrence?_" By not tinkering around with internal data in the `config` database directly. Use helper functions instead, such as [movePrimary](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/movePrimary/). This is not about programming and is a better question for [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It's a bad idea to modify internal databases